# View Events by Category using PHP Code Igniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm a not that advance in **PHP**, I need some assistance:

I have a table `events` with column name `event_type`

I want when I click `business` I would get all events under `business` category. Same goes to `education`...

This is my views, [View Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlWmq.png)

This is a code snippet from by views, `business` category.
`

```
                <div class="sell-or-buy">

                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="et-line-briefcase"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="content">

                        <h3 class="uppercase">Business</h3>

                        <p>
                            Business is always Good when you talk of a good setup. Get
                            the best Meetings right here.
                                <br>
                        </p>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/category' . $data['event_type'])?>">View</a>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>`
```

I dont know how to configure my **controller** and my **model**

.
I am using **Code Igniter 3.0 with PHP**

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Please post what you done so far..You can't expect your work do be get done completely from here.So be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.So what i get from your question is,you had table `events` with `event_type` and you want to fetch the event data depending on event clicked/triggered.

From your posted URL,it looks like `Home` is your controller and `category` is the function and you are passing `event_type` to that function

```
<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/category/' . $data['event_type'])?>
```

So your controller function will go like this (I hope you are following CI user guide to define controller);

```
//Controller function
    function category($event_type)
    {

    // pass the received event_type to your model
    $this->load->model('event_model');
    $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_events($event_type);

    // Pass the data to your views
    $this->load->view('events',$data);
}


// Model code goes like this
function get_events($event_type)
{
  **// result() returns object where as result_array() returns array**
   $query = $this->db->get_where('events',array('event_type'=>$event_type))->result();
   if (count($query) > 0)
   {
      return $query;
   }
   else
      return false;
}
```

Let me know if any queries.

Comment: Im getting _Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on array

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\evento\application\models\home_model.php

Line Number: 53

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\evento\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 123
Function: categories

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\evento\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once_     `

Comment: Thanks alot  no I gave up, it became quite complicated, but below I have found the answer, it was much simpler...see below @Anowar

Comment: Ok.Your call but please consider to work and write the best code because when your project goes big,scalability is the main concern

Comment: Thanks......im trying it now i get this _An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\evento\application\views\searchview\category.php

Line Number: 122

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\evento\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 146
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\evento\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once_

Comment: The error say it all, the query i have shown it return result as object and you are trying to parse it as array.So for your view code to work ,in model make this change.Instead of `result()` make it `result_array()`

Added comment in code.You can check my comment also

Comment: Yaaaiy, Thanks @Zeeshan, Works like majic, Im now able to view my categories.....Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

> Without model dependency

**Home Controller:**

```
public function category($event_type= false){
    if($event_type !=false){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('event_type', $event_type);
        $data[events] = $this->db->get('events')->result_array();

        //Also query & pass all event_type into view $data[event_type]
        $this->load->view('category_view', $data);
    }else{
        redirect('index.php/home/index'); //might be home page
    }
}
```

**category_view:**

```
 //Foreach events data by $events or check by var_dump($events)
//Generate url by foreach event_type or use custom 
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/category/business')?>">Business</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/category/education')?>">Education</a>
```

### -------------------------------or----------------------------------------

> Edited: With model (Using model and common query function).

**controller:**

```
public function category($event_type= false){
    if($event_type !=false){
        $this->load->model('model_name');

        $where = array('event_type'=>$event_type);
        $data[events] = $this->model_name->get_data('events', $where));

        //Also query & pass all event_type into view $data[event_type]
        $this->load->view('category_view', $data);
    }else{
        redirect('index.php/home/index'); //might be home page
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function get_data($table, $where=false){
    $this->db->select('*');
    if($where != false){ 
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    return $this->db->get($table)->result_array();

}
```

Comment: This redirects to my home without the results

Comment: If you are removing model dependency, you are breaking the MVC concept. Also its not good idea to execute your queries in controller as Model is for that.

Comment: @Zeeshan noted, Thanks, I  try to do adjustments to my code

Comment: Why we use model? is it mandatory  for each and every action?
We use model for database related operation, validation, common function etc.
Here @RobertKibet was in trouble so i think no need to make complex.
If you want to use model then just create a db query function in model and use that function in controller instead of  direct query.

Comment: This question shouldn't rise why Use model ? If you have decided to use MVC.
Also its for our sake.